# How to disregard attendance/absentees/late count for a holiday date in attendance_tbl in database?

Tags: php, mysql

So here is my code:

```
SELECT s.student_id as 'Student_Number', CONCAT(IFNULL(s.student_fname,''),' ', IFNULL(s.student_mname,''),' ', IFNULL(s.student_lname,'')) 'Student_Name',s.student_program as 'Program', (SUM(IF(stat.status_description='Late',1,0))) 'Total_Lates', (SUM(IF(stat.status_description='Absent',1,0))) 'Total_Absences', Floor((SUM(IF(stat.status_description='Late',1,0))) / 3 + (SUM(IF(stat.status_description='Absent',1,0)))) 'Total_Absence_with_Lates' FROM attendance_tbl a LEFT JOIN student_tbl s ON s.student_id=a.entity_id LEFT JOIN status_tbl stat ON stat.status_id=a.status_id where a.course_id='$course' and a.entity_type='student' and CONCAT(IFNULL(s.student_fname,''),' ', IFNULL(s.student_mname,''),' ', IFNULL(s.student_lname,'')) like '%$stname%' GROUP BY a.entity_id, CONCAT(IFNULL(s.student_fname,''),' ', IFNULL(s.student_mname,''),' ', IFNULL(s.student_lname,'')) order by Student_Name ASC
```

I  am counting absences for each student. 1 absent = 1 absent and 3 lates = 1 absent.

Here is the output of my query:

[image]

This is the tables i am getting the data FROM:

ATTENDANCE_TBL: its rows are:

```
attendance_id | entity_id | course_id | rooms_id | status_id | date | time | term | entity_type
```

this table is basically the attendance of students. status id is just integer type from 1-5 1 means present, 2 - late, 3 -absent, 4- excused , 5-cutting.

I also have STATUS_TBL: its rows are: status_id | status_description
status id is from 1-5 then the description is 1 means present, 2 - late, 3 -absent, 4- excused , 5-cutting.

STUDENT_TBL rows:

```
student_id | studant_fname | studant_mname | studant_lname | student_program
```

student_program is the course of the student like tourism, entrepreneurship and etc...

Overall, this is the problem I want help with: I want to disregard the absences count for the days that is a holiday.

I have holiday_table:

it has

```
announcement_id | announcement_date | announcement_description | term
```

if the announcement_date is same with the date in the attendance_tbl and also the term in holiday_table to attendance_tbl it will disregard the attendance/absentees/late count on that day. basically it won't count it

Comment: I'm not sure I grok ("understand") the concept of "announcement_date"?  It seems the logic should be, "if student is absent on the date of a holiday, do not count an absence."  However, there's an even better question: if the date is a holiday, why would there even be a class event/entry with that date?

Comment: your answer seems right it shouldn't let entry on holiday, however we havent done that logic first in the first place :<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do a left join of attendance table to holiday_table on announcement_date and term, check if the holiday date is null, then your original query will not count those dates that are considered holidays.  You did not give us the columns for attendance_tbl so you can figure out the query below.

```
select <...>
FROM attendance_tbl a 
LEFT JOIN holiday_table h ON h.announcement_date = a.<date_column> and h.term = a.term
where h.announcement_date is null
and ...
Group By...
order by Student_Name ASC;
```